# Some test cases satisfied while others not

Tags: java, arraylist

My program is supposed to be passed 2 array-lists, arrivals and duration, and should return the number of events that can basically take place without overlap. However, a-lot of testcases are not being passed successfully. Below is shown an expected output:

```
arrivals = [1,3,3,5,7]
duration = [2,2,1,2,1]
```

The first person arrives at 1, presents for 2 hours, then leaves. 2 people arrive at 3 but only one is allowed to present for 2 or 1 hours. The next person arrives at 5, presents for 2 hours. The final person arrives at 7, and presents for 1 hour. The answer output should be 4 as 4 people are able to present. Below is my current program:

```
class Result {
public static int maxEvents(List<Integer> arrival,List<Integer> duration) {
        int counter = 0;
        if (arrival.size() == 0) {
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (arrival.get(i) + duration.get(i) <= arrival.get(i + 1)) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (arrival.get(i).equals(arrival.get(i + 1))) {
                    counter++;
                    i++;
                } else if (arrival.get(arrival.size()-1).equals(arrival.get(i))) {
                  counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

This program works for test cases such as:

```
arrival = [1,1,1,1,4]
duration = [10,3,4,6,2]
Output: 2
```

But fails for cases such as below:

```
arrival = [1,3,5]
duration = [2,2,2]
Expected:3
Mine:2
```

or:

```
 arrival = [1]
 duration = [5]
 Expected = 1
 Mine = 0
```

I can't seem to be able to see what the issue could be.

A user in the comments submitted his logic on the problem and below is the implantation:

```
class Result {
public static int maxEvents(List<Integer> arrival,List<Integer> duration) {
       int counter = 0;
       if (arrival.size() == 0) {
         return 0;
       } else  {
          counter = 1;
          ArrayList <Integer> timeseq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for (int i = 0;i< arrival.size(); i++) {
            timeseq.add(arrival.get(i));
            timeseq.add(arrival.get(i)+duration.get(i));
          }
          for (int j =1; j<= timeseq.size()-2; j+=2) {
            if(timeseq.get(j) <= timeseq.get(j+1)) {
              counter++;
            }
          }
        return counter;
      }
  }
}
```

This code fails the test case

```
 arrival = (1,1,1,1,4) duration = (10,3,6,4.2)
Expected = 2 
Mine = 1
```

Comment: If size is `1`, then `i < arrival.size() - 1` will always be `false` therefore loop will never be entered.

Comment: @Nexevis How do you implement a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confusing .size() with .length(). These are different methods and they have different returns. Considering @Nexevis answer, maybe remove the "-1" since you're calling for the size of the array.

Comment: Doing this makes the program fail all test cases whereas before it was passing half of them. I don't think the size is the issue, but the fact I may need an additional else if condition

Answer (score 0):

I would normally do it differently. Below is a brief about the logic I would implement. Note that its a pseudo code:

```
    if arrival size = 0, return 0;
    else counter = 1
    timesequencearray = [] <- Array to hold time sequence. Should be double the size of arrival array
    //Prepare an array which contains the time sequence based on the events 
    for(i=0 to arrival.size()){
    timesequencearray.push(arrival.get(i));
    timesequencearray.push(arrival.get(i)+distance.get(i));
    } 
    for (i=1 to timesequencearray.size()-2; i= i+2){
    if(timesequencearray[i]<=timesequencearray[i+1]:
     counter++;
    }
    return counter;
```

Below is the working of the code. Say your input is 
[1,2,3]
[1,1,2]
timesequencearray will be [1,2,2,3,3,5] and we will check if "2" on the index 1 is less than or equal to "2" on index 2 (this means no overlap). So increase the counter. Counter is kept "1" in the beginning to imply that the last arrival is never overlapping. Lets take your failed case:

```
arrival = [1,3,5]

duration = [2,2,2]

timesequencearray - [1,3,3,5,5,7]
3<=3 -> counter = 2
5<=5 -> counter = 3
Return counter = 3
```

Another one:

```
arrival = [1]

duration = [5]

timesequencearray = [1,6]
```

No loop is executed. Counter = 1 is returned as the size of arrival is greater than zero.

Comment: I implemented your pseudocode logic and while it did work on the 2 example testcases you showed above, it failed some of the others which were successful before. An example is arrival = (1,1,1,1,4) and duration = (10,3,6,4,2). The code outputs 1 whereas expected = 2.

Comment: I also pasted the implementation of your pseudocode in the post